# Scala, PureConfig - how to read json config file?

Tags: scala, scala-cats, circe, pureconfig

I have a simple `config.json` file in my resources:

```
{
  "configs": [
    {
      "someConfig": {
        "name": "my_name",
        "filters": {
          "name": "new"
        },
        "id": "some-config-id",
        "fixes": {
          "isFixed": true
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I also created `case classes` for given fields:

```
final case class Configs(configs: List[SomeConfig])

  final case class SomeConfig(name: String,
                              filters: Filters,
                              id: String,
                              fixes: Fixes)

  final case class Filters(name: String)

  final case class Fixes(isFixed: Boolean)
```

Now I want to read this config file with `PureConfig`:

```
val configs: Configs = ConfigSource.resources("configs.json").loadOrThrow[Configs]
```

But I got errors:

```
Exception in thread "main" pureconfig.error.ConfigReaderException: Cannot convert configuration to Configs. Failures are:
- Key not found: 'name'.
- Key not found: 'filters'.
- Key not found: 'id'.
- Key not found: 'fixes'
```

I added also `ProductHint`:

```
 implicit def hint[A] = ProductHint[A](ConfigFieldMapping(CamelCase, CamelCase))
```

But it did not help.
How I could fix it to read configs from `json` file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your case classes don't match JSON. It should be something more like:

```
{
  "configs": [
    {
      "name": "my_name",
      "filters": {
        "name": "new"
      },
      "id": "some-config-id",
      "fixes": {
        "isFixed": true
      }
    }     
  ]
}
```

Notice the lack of `"someConfig": { ... }` as a wrapper for config object. Alternatively you should have:

```
final case class Configs(configs: List[SomeConfigWrapper])

final case class SomeConfigWrapper(someConfig: SomeConfig)

...
```

because in the JSON you don't have `name`, `filters`, `id` and `fixes` immediately within `"configs"` object.